# unable to disable the jquery element on the web page

Tags: jquery-ui

i have build a jquery functionality where i want the whole functionality to get disable when the user presses the corresponding button(hide/disable etc).

for this i have used the

$('#id').hide();

which only hides the elements on the web page of the functionality but not the functionality(hope you can understand this)
like i am able to delete the text in a textbox but not the textbox itself(weird example)
what i want is to make the div(of the functionality to get dis appear)

one more thing even when the elemnts get hidden, on refreshing the web page same elemnts are once again popped on the field

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#id').remove()
```

It will remove the element from the DOM entirely. Once you refresh the page, it'll be back where it was.

Comment: done 
once refreshed the same thing(which i want to get disappeared) appears again

Comment: the same thing happens with both the hide() and remove()

Answer (score 0):

Your textbox is going to always come back when you refresh the page if it's in the markup as visible by default.

You could dynamically create this textbox on-the-fly based on a cookie that holds a boolean value indicating if it should be visible or not that would be set during the hide or show.

You could also leave it in the markup but use `display: none;` so it's not visible by default, and then toggle it based on some value (again cookie or something of that nature).

Comment: textbox was just an illusionistic illustration nnothing concerned withh the textbox here
please answer what is asked

Comment: @Roadrunner - First of all, you need to word your questions in a professional manner if you want real help.  Your lack of sentence structure, grammar, English in general, makes it very tough to read.  Secondly, you need to post relevant code that shows what you have tried that's not working.  That does much more justice than your explanation.  Lastly, if your textbox was an illusionistic illustration, then so is my answer. All you would have to do is swap out the word textbox for div or elements or whatever you are trying to make disappear permanently.

Comment: ok sir(sorry for being rude)
i tried div.parent.remove()
it worked but what i realised is that only a part of the div has vanished there is no way roun to recognize the other part

Comment: No worries.  If you can edit your question and post your HTML and jQuery that you are trying, that would be your best bet.  Without seeing some sort of markup structure or jQuery, it's almost impossible to answer with certainty.